# Html link with pre-search?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Is there a way to write an html link to include a search for a particular term? For example, a link to http://news.google.com/ where all the words of Nato have been highlighted by the browser, as if you clicked, pressed Ctrl-F and wrote Nato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, unless the website you’re linking to offers such an API, e.g.

```
http://example.com/?highlight=nato
```

…which would then process the document on the server-side and highlight the terms in some way.

Either way, **it’s impossible** to make the browser highlight these things yourself unless the user actually searches for it himself.

Comment: Fortunately this is not possible.